# Vertically Center a Bootstrap Popover to Viewport

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get all my popovers to be vertically centered to the viewport. My project requirements prevent me from using a Bootstrap Modal which would be an easier choice.

So, the popover triggers on link click. Have set the link to

```
position: relative;
```

As for the Bootstrap popover div, it has been set to

```
position: absolute;
```

**I have tried setting the body display to table-cell and the bootstrap popover div to table-cell and vertical-align: middle; but nothing works.**

Unable to give you guys an example code. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your issue without sample code. Can you recreate issue here?

Comment: @ketan Thanks for trying to help Ketan. I was unable to show an example as I am using too much of JS on my website and unable to find relevant code for the popover. fixed it with seahorsepip's solution. Set it to `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: absolute;
```

Is positioning based on the parents element with position relative, absolute or fixed.

Remove the link it's `position: relative;` or try `position: fixed` instead of absolute.